# Adding button and onClickListener to widget in Android Studio, the app is based on React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to add a button to my app's widget which is based on React Native,

I've created the widget, and it's been linked correctly to the app. Some text come from the react-native app displayed on the widget.

here is the files I've created so far, but I don't know how to handle the onClick event.

MainApplication.java:

```
package com.easyremember;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
            packages.add(new SharedStoragePackager());

            return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
    }
    com.easyremember.ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.easyremember;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */

  Button btn;

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "easyremember";
  }


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


  }


  /**
   * Returns the instance of the {@link ReactActivityDelegate}. Here we use a util class {@link
   * DefaultReactActivityDelegate} which allows you to easily enable Fabric and Concurrent React
   * (aka React 18) with two boolean flags.
   */
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
            this,
            getMainComponentName(),
            // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
            DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled());
  }


}
```

MyWidget.java:

```
package com.easyremember;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.easyremember.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    Button btn;





    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

        try {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String appString = sharedPref.getString("appData", "{\"text\":'no data'}");
            JSONObject appData = new JSONObject(appString);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, appData.getString("text"));
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }




    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }


}
```

my_widget.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/Widget.Easyremember.AppWidget.Container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppWidgetContainer">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
        style="@style/Widget.Easyremember.AppWidget.InnerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />



    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SharedStorage.java:

```
package com.easyremember;


import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

public class SharedStorage extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    ReactApplicationContext context;

    public SharedStorage(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        context = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "SharedStorage";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void set(String message) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("appData", message);
        editor.commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getCurrentActivity().getApplicationContext(), MyWidget.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getCurrentActivity().getApplicationContext()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getCurrentActivity().getApplicationContext(), MyWidget.class));
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
        getCurrentActivity().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
}
```

SharedStoragePackager.java:

```
package com.easyremember;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SharedStoragePackager implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new SharedStorage(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }

}
```

However, the problem is with adding a button to my widget that has an on click listener. Whenever I click this button, I want to throw a new Toast or increase an integer number (action is not important).